# Add onclick event listeners to multiple buttons with Handlebar.js templates, only the last one is effective

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm writing a web app as a homework project that uses websocket to receive messages from a server and display them on html using handlebars.js.

I'm trying to implement the function of deleting a message using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ...
    let message_container = document.querySelector("#message_container");
    const message_template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector("#message_template").innerHTML);
    const delete_button_template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector("#delete_button_template").innerHTML);

    function addDeleteButton(id) {
        let con = delete_button_template({"message_id": id}); //line #1
        document.querySelector("#content_" + id).innerHTML += con;
        document.querySelector("#delete_button_" + id).onclick = function () {
            const msg_id = event.target.dataset.message_id;
            const msg = document.querySelector("#message_" + msg_id);
            const blank = document.querySelector("#message_" + msg_id + "_newline");
            msg.parentElement.removeChild(msg);
            blank.parentElement.removeChild(blank);
        }
    }
```

The function for adding the message to the DOM is simple:

```
function newMessage(i) {
            let msg = message_template({
                "message_id": i.message_id,
                "username": ...,
                "timestamp": ...,
                "content": ...
            });
            message_container.innerHTML += msg;
            addDeleteButton(i.message_id);
    }
```

The handlebars.js Template for the delete button is plugged into HTML as following:

```
<button id="delete_button_{{ message_id }}" data-message_id="{{ message_id }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                Delete
</button>
```

However, every time I add a new message (including the delete button) to the DOM, all previous buttons lose their onclick() event listeners.
A chrome inspector shows this clearly and it happens at line #1: 
[The 4th button has an event listener registered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flCn2.jpg)

[Adding the 5th button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWnwA.png)

[The onclick event of the 4th button disappeared.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAlwb.jpg)

A clear workaround is to embed the onclick call into the  html attribute.
But why can't I register the event listeners like the given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

`message_container.innerHTML += msg;`

We are using Handlebars to produce a new string of HTML which we are storing to the `msg` variable. We then want to *append* that new HTML to the `#message_container` DOM element.

However, `message_container.innerHTML += msg` does *not* simply append our new HTML to the `#message_container`, instead, it *replaces all of the descendant DOM nodes of* `#message_container`!

A breakdown of what happens is:

- We get the descendant nodes of the `#message_container` in the DOM,    stringified into an HTML string.
- `msg` is concatenated onto the end of this new HTML string.
- The new HTML string *replaces* the `innerHTML` of `#message_container`.

The important part here is the *replacement*. When the `innerHTML` of `#message_container` is replaced, *all of its descendant nodes are replaced*. So all of the `<button>`s that you have previously attached `onclick` listeners to have been removed from the DOM.

One way to prevent replacing all the children of `#message_container` each time we want to add a `<button>` would be to use the [`Node.appendChild()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). The resultant code would look like:

```
// message_container.innerHTML += msg; // TODO: Replace this line with the below.

const node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = msg;
message_container.appendChild(node);
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vwxayus8/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! Saved lots of debugging time.
I also wonder whether there is extensive documentation about all these behaviours of the DOM. The MDN is highly detailed but lack of highlights of these special outcomes.

Comment: I don't know that I would call this a "special outcome". By using `.innerHTML` you are creating a fresh DOM tree under the target node. All nodes that you had previously attached listeners to get removed. This is the trade-off when you use a blunt instrument like `.innerHTML` over interacting with the DOM as a tree of Objects.